# change TableView Lines [iPhone SDK]

Tags: iphone

Does it way to change the TableView Lines ? just like this :

[image]
<sub>(source: [khmeriphone at sites.google.com](https://sites.google.com/site/khmeriphone/IMG_0065.jpg))</sub>

the lines become wood image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try using an imageview with the wooden image. Which is added to your custom cell. Because I think iphone-sdk does not support to modify the separators. And one thing set separator style as none for the table view.

Hope this helps.

Comment: so ! what did he do ? ? [developer of WeDict APP]  ?

Comment: (1) He set the table to show no separator between cells. (1) He created a customer UITableViewCell that has an image of a wood grain running along bottom of the view. This creates the illusion of separator when the table actually has none.

Comment: is there any sample code or tutorial of this ? or can you write the code ? :)